# Ag-Grid Angular - How to enable Hyperlink for one of the columns

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am changing code from Kendo Grid to Ag-Grid and I am facing problem in making the link work with Ag-Grid

Below is the old code which is placed in one of the columns of Kendo Grid

```
<a *ngIf="dataItem.userStatus === 0"
[routerLink]="['/users/details/'+dataItem.userId]">{{dataItem.userName}}</a>
<span *ngIf="dataItem.userStatus === 1">{{dataItem.userName}}</span>
```

I am defining the new column in Ag-Grid with columnDefs as below

```
{
    headerName: 'User Name',
    minWidth: 150,
    width: 250,
    field: 'userName',
    cellRendererFramework: RouterLinkRendererComponent,
    cellRendererParams: {
      inRouterLink: '[/users/details/]',
    }
  },
```

Below is the code for `RouterLinkRendererComponent`

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AgRendererComponent } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
    template: '<a [routerLink]="[params.inRouterLink,params.value]"  (click)="navigate(params.inRouterLink)">{{params.value}}</a>'
})
export class RouterLinkRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
    params: any;

    constructor(
        private ngZone: NgZone,
        private router: Router) { }

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    refresh(params: any): boolean {
        return false;
    }

    // This was needed to make the link work correctly
    navigate(link) {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate([link, this.params.value]);
        });
    }
}
```

How to make the Hyperlink work for UserName column with new Ag-Grid

Currently, the error is coming as below. Please consider `assetName` as `userName` below when I modify the template `<a [routerLink]="[params.inRouterLink, params.value]"  (click)="navigate(params.inRouterLink)">{{params.data.assetName}}</a>` and it is coming for each row repeatedly

[image: AssetName Error]

I have added my code in Stackblitz below.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rojbjy?file=src/app/router-link-renderer/router-link-renderer.component.ts)

I am getting the below error when I add ag-angular-grid in `app.component.html` file in `Stackblitz`. This is because of mismatch in the versions of the file. I need solution in **`Angular 6`**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just don't import RouterModule or miss forRoot method on RouterModule. Also you need to make sure that you have the same AgGridModule.withComponents with your renderer component. There is an example where links are works:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-ynuufr)

Comment: I am so excited with your answer. But still I am getting errors in the console. Please consider `assetName` as the value I am going to click instead of `userName` and I am getting the error for each row of the grid in my code `<a [routerLink]="[params.inRouterLink, params.value]"  (click)="navigate(params.inRouterLink)">{{params.data.assetName}}</a>`. The error is attached in the modified question.

Comment: @CPK_2011 this error means that you set the wrong data for the cell. You can use optional chaining to handle empty data or debug ag-grid params to make sure the data which you need in that component is exist.

Comment: I am stuck here. The example provided by you does not navigate to the details page also. Could you please help me out on this?

Comment: @CPK_2011 could you represent your issue in stackblitz?

Comment: I have added my code in Stackblitz in the Question at the bottom. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @CPK_2011 didn't see any data which you pass into a ag grid, your example is just a code without any simulated situation :)

Comment: In your Stackblitz code you have displayed the data with ag-grid. That would be enough for me. But here I just want the navigation to details page on click of AssetName cell in the grid :).

Comment: It is getting complicated when I add this code -- `<div style="width: 200px;">
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"
  class="ag-theme-fresh"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
</ag-grid-angular>
</div>` to `app.component.html` and getting error as attached to the question in Stackblitz. Please help me on this. Just if I add `ag-angular-grid` without errors then it would reach your way of showing the data in the Grid.

Comment: @CPK_2011 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-91xow3 I have fixed errors. Pay attention to grid data that you pass into a grid. If you want to bind data like "assetName" you must make sure that it exists in rowData.
this.gridOptions.rowData = [
      { id: 5, value: 10, assetStatus: 0, assetName: 'foo' },
      { id: 10, value: 15, assetStatus: 1, assetName: 'bar' },
      { id: 15, value: 20, assetStatus: 0, assetName: 'baz' },
    ];(app.component.ts 35 row)
When I click on "foo" row angular trying to navigate, but in stackblitz this route doesn't exist, it should work on your app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241549/discussion-between-cpk-2011-and-yan-koshelev).